# When URL suffixed by a file extension, Spring Restful ControllerAdvice exception handler response html

Tags: spring, rest, exception

I use @RestControllerAdvice to handle exception thrown by a controller globally, and response json string to client.  My rest controller @RequestMapping path can accept URL suffixed by a file extension. If the controller throw a exception and URL is suffixed by a known extension , the exception handler will response html instead of json.

build.gradle

```
...
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
     compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:8.0.33'
     compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.1.RELEASE'
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
...
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo"/>
...
```

DemoController.java

```
@RestController
public class DemoRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name:.+}")
    public String doSomething(@PathVariable String name){
       throw new  RuntimeException(name);
    }
}
```

RestExceptionHandler

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public Message handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
           Message ret=new Message(System.currentTimeMillis(),ex.getMessage());
           return ret;
    }
}
```

client

```
$ curl localhost:8080/abc                     //no extension, it's ok
{"time":1479235304196,"url":"abc"}            
$ curl localhost:8080/abc.opq                 //unknown extension, ok
{"time":1479235545303,"url":"abc.opq"}
$ curl localhost:8080/abc.jpg
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.33 - Error report</title> ...
...
```

the last output is html, it is not i want, what's matter?  can you help me , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the request path has an unknown extension then Spring doesn't know what to do with the return value from handleException and falls back to HTML. You can fix this by rendering JSON directly in your handleException method. This worked in my case because my API always returns JSON in the case of errors, instead of protobuf or csv or whatever.

```
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = {RestController.class})
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public ApiExceptionHandler(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void exceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Exception x) throws IOException {
        Message ret = new Message(System.currentTimeMillis(),ex.getMessage());
        res.setStatus(500);
        res.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8.toString());
        objectMapper.writeValue(res.getOutputStream(), ret);
    }
}
```